# PHPExcel Conditional Formatting

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an excel file with 2 sheets.
One for some raw data and the other one is a dashboard with only formulas.
Some cells from the dashboard sheet are set up to with a conditional formatting.

I use PHPExcel to open this file and then to feel up the raw data sheet. But when the work is done the whole format of my dashboard sheet is bugged. For example the cells set up with a % format are shown in a decimal format and Excel doesn't want to change it back to a % format.

To fill up my raw data sheet I use the exact same code as [read and write using phpexcel while using listWorksheetNames()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506185/read-and-write-using-phpexcel-while-using-listworksheetnames)

When I remove the Conditional Formatting formula everything works fine and I don't have any bug.

Comment: can you please share you code?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$cell->getFormattedValue();
```

Comment: Thanks, can i do that through $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A1")->getFormattedValue(); But it doesn't work i got the error message: "Invalid cell coordinate A' in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexcel\PHPExcel_1.7.9\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:298 Stack trace: #0 "